# Add BackDrop in WPF

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

I need to add backdrop on some element when dropdown is open.

What I mean - in Bootstrap when you open modal window - backround become dark and not clickable (for default settings) [(Live example)](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#live-demo)

Should I add trigger on dropDown open event which will add some background (backdrop) on some element and make this element disabled?

Comment: There is no such term (backdrop?) in wpf. Menu is a special kind of window and it seems you want it to behave like a normal modal window (disabling parent window interactions and possibly providing some visual to signal about it). Then why use menu? Open another window modally and make it *looking like menu*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution.

I've just added some Grid with ZIndex and Background.

This Grid become visible when Toggle Button is checked and unvisible in another case(when click on this GRID (Overlay) - then I force Toggle Button being clicked - this is how I've managed to hide GRID... something simple to Bootstrap behaviour of Modal Backdrop).

```
<Grid x:Name="Overlay" Panel.ZIndex="2" Grid.Row="1">
        <Grid.Background>
            <SolidColorBrush Color="Black" Opacity=".3"/>
        </Grid.Background>
        <Grid.Style>
            <Style TargetType="Grid">
                <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsChecked, ElementName=FiltersButton}" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
                    </DataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </Grid.Style>
        <Grid.Triggers>
            <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="UIElement.MouseDown">
                <EventTrigger.Actions>
                    <BeginStoryboard>
                        <Storyboard>
                            <BooleanAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="FiltersButton" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(ToggleButton.IsChecked)">
                                <DiscreteBooleanKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:00.0" Value="False" />
                            </BooleanAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                        </Storyboard>
                    </BeginStoryboard>
                </EventTrigger.Actions>
            </EventTrigger>
        </Grid.Triggers>
    </Grid>
```

Maybe there are another way (more simple or with less code) to bind logic of visibility...

Answer (score 1):

Here is a very robust mimic of effect you want.

xaml:

```
<Grid>
    <TextBlock Text="SomeContent" />
    <Button Content="Click"
            HorizontalAlignment="Center"
            VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
            Click="Button_Click">
        <Button.ContextMenu>
            <ContextMenu Opened="ContextMenu_Opened"
                         Closed="ContextMenu_Closed">
                <MenuItem Header="Test" />
            </ContextMenu>
        </Button.ContextMenu>
    </Button>
    <Grid x:Name="overlay"
          Visibility="Collapsed"
          Background="#50000000" />
</Grid>
```

cs:

```
void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) => ((Button)sender).ContextMenu.IsOpen = true;
void ContextMenu_Opened(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) => overlay.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
void ContextMenu_Closed(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) => overlay.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
```

Here is how it works:

[image]

Idea is to create semi-transparent layer (backdrop?) which is shown when menu is opened.

It should be easy to improve this: use bindings, add effects, etc.